# LDAP v3 service on top of couchdb or cloudant

Tags: ldap, couchdb, cloudant

We have a requirement to move existing data from our LDAP server to couchdb or cloudant. We want to use the inherent cloudant replication than setting up native LDAP replications.

For our clients, we need to provide an LDAP v3 interface to access that data.

Are their any existing LDAP servers or "virtual" LDAP servers that can work with cloudant as the back end ? Or if any directory servers where a new backend can be added with some customization ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any LDAP to Cloudant migration tools. Neither product can speak to each other natively.

You could think about modelling your LDAP data as JSON for starters. An LDAP entry like this:

```
 dn: cn=John Doe,dc=example,dc=com
 cn: John Doe
 givenName: John
 sn: Doe
 telephoneNumber: +1 888 555 6789
 telephoneNumber: +1 888 555 1232
 mail: john@example.com
 manager: cn=Barbara Doe,dc=example,dc=com
 objectClass: inetOrgPerson
 objectClass: organizationalPerson
 objectClass: person
 objectClass: top
```

could become:

```
{
  "_id": "johndoe.example.com",
  "dc": "example.com",
  "cn": "John Doe",
  "givenName": "John",
  "sn": "Doe",
  "telephoneNumber": [ "+1 888 555 6789", "+1 888 555 1232 ],
  "mail": "john@example.com",
  "manager": "barbaradoe.example.com",
  "objectClass": ["inetOrgPerson","organizationalPerson","person","top"]
}
```

The choice of `_id`, Cloudant's unique identifier per document, is important to get right of course. Once you have your data as JSON, you can insert it into Cloudant using the [bulk API](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#bulk-operations) (in batches of, say, 500).

You can certainly model all of the LDAP key/values but thought would be given as to how you would want to retrieve and search the data once in Cloudant. You could start with [Cloudant Query](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query), but there are other options like [Map/Reduce Views](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/creating_views.html#views-mapreduce-) and [full-text search](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search).